# Why I am unable to retrieve the composer caching folder dir on aws codebuild?

Tags: php, caching, composer-php, aws-codebuild

In my project in order to speed up the build I atempt to cache the composer caching folder using the following `buildspec.yml`:

```
version: 0.2

env:
  variables:
    COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR: "${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR}/.cache/composer"

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - apk add --update git
      - echo ${COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR}
      - mkdir -p ${COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR}
      - ls -l ${COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR}
  build:
    commands:
      - ls -l ${COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR}
      - ls -l vendor
      - composer install --no-dev --no-progress --no-suggest --optimize-autoloader
      - ls -l ${COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR}

artifacts:
  files:
    - app/**/*
    - bootstrap/**/*
    - config/**/*
    - database/**/*
    - machine/**/*
    - public/**/*
    - resources/**/*
    - routes/**/*
    - scripts/**/*
    - vendor/**/*
    - .env
    - appspec.yml
    - artisan
    - composer.json

cache:
  paths:
    - ${COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR}
```

But once the build runs once I `ls -l ${COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR}` is executed it shows an empty folder:

```
[Container] 2020/04/23 07:28:43 Running command ls -l ${COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR}

total 0
```

But once `composer install` is being executed then the `COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR` is being populated:

```
[Container] 2020/04/23 07:29:36 Running command ls -l ${COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR}
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   41 root     root          4096 Apr 23 07:29 files
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Apr 23 07:28 repo
```

So I wonder why the codebuild is unable to populate the `COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR` folder on `install` phase? I cheched the S3 and the files are being placed as expected. I also placed no expiration on my cache as well and I use my own docker image instead of amazon-provided one.

Comment: Have you checked whether Composer really used that directory, such that any files are stored there?

Comment: Yes I checked that the composer does store data in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is something to do with the variable substitution format you are using or the cache paths format. Check below for a working sample. In first run there will be nothing in cache directory, in second run, files will be populated:

```
version: 0.2

env:
  variables:
    COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR: .cache/composer

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - ls -al .
      - ls -l .cache/composer
      - echo .cache/composer
      - mkdir -p .cache/composer
      - ls -l .cache/composer

  build:
    commands:
      - ls -l .cache/composer
      - touch .cache/composer/a.txt
      - touch .cache/composer/b.txt
      - pwd
      - ls -al

cache:
  paths:
    - .cache/composer/**/*
```